# How submit elements <option> inside <select> to server without need to select them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form where I have two `<select>`: the first one are filled dinamically through a jquery script which read data from a json file and a second one to where the user transfer the items he want submit to server.

Right now, the user can only submit the items when he MANUALLY submit the items. I don't want that because the user already have to select this same data from the first select. Anyone can tell me how to acomplish that?

**html code**

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
    <select class="all all_address" size="10" multiple="multiple">
    </select>
    </td>

<td>
    <p> <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-default" id="for_left_1"> << </button> </p>
    <p> <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-default" id="for_right_1"> >> </button> </p>
</td>

    <td>
    <select name="address" class="lista lista_address" size="10" multiple="multiple">
    </select>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**jquery code**

```
$(document).on('submit', '.form', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var $form = $( this ),
    url = $form.attr( "action" );

    var posting = $.post( url, $(this).serialize() );
    posting.done(function( data ) {
        $("#"+data).css("display", "block");

        $(".form").each (function(){
            this.reset();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'the user already has to select the same data from the first select' - do you mean that you don't want to lose the options used to populate the first select on the POST? That would be more about your server-side logic then. Sorry if I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: No, I just want send to server only the content from the second select, but right now, after transfer the items for this select, I need select all of them before click in the submit button. I want avoid this step.