# jquery script aren't being executed inside my spring project

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, jsp

In my spring project, I have a page dashboard.jsp (based on this [example](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/screenshots/dashboard.jpg)) where I load all my css and js files, and I load all my other jsp files too - I obtain the file using `$.get()` or `$.ajax()` and load its content in a structure like that:

```
<div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
    <div id="content" class="panel panel-warning" style="display: none;">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 id="titulo" class="panel-title"></h3>
      </div>
      <div id="conteudo" class="panel-body">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is done by a script called page_link.js which have this functions:

```
function open(url) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url
    }).done(function( data ) {
        var $temp  = $('<div/>', {html:data});
        var titulo = $temp.find('title').text();
        var conteudo = $temp.remove('head').html();
        $("#titulo").empty();
        $("#conteudo").empty();
        $("#titulo").text(titulo);
        $("#conteudo").html(conteudo);
        $("#content").show();
    });
}

function open_dialog(url, dialog_div) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url
    }).done(function(data){
        var $temp  = $('<div/>', {html:data});
        var text = $(dialog_div).find('#text');
        $( dialog_div ).dialog({ title: $temp.find('title').text() });
        $( text ).html($temp.remove('head').html());
        $( dialog_div ).dialog({ height: 720 });
        $( dialog_div ).dialog({ width: 720 });
        $( dialog_div ).dialog( "open" );
    });
}

$(document).on('click', '.link', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var action = $(this).data('action');
    open(action);
});

$(document).on('click', '.popup', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var action = $(this).data('action');
    var target = $(this).data('target');
    var div = $("#"+target);
    open_dialog(action, div);
});

$(document).on('click', '.pagina', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    open(link);
});
```

the pages where I have some form which need br submited to server (all via method POST), this is done by a script called form_submit.js, with that code:

```
$(document).on('submit', '.form', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var $form = $( this ),
    url = $form.attr( "action" );

    if($("select.lista").length) {
        jQuery('select.lista').find('option.item').each(function(){
            $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
        });
    }

    var posting = $.post( url, $(this).serialize() );
    posting.done(function( data ) {
        $("#"+data).css("display", "block");

        if($("#pergunta").is(":visible"))
            $("#pergunta").css("display", "none");

        $(".form").each (function(){
            this.reset();
        });
    });
});
```

this two scripts are working fine (except for a tiny part of the second, explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004567/how-submit-elements-option-inside-select-to-server-without-need-to-select-th)). But this third one, where I do validation of some fields (which have the class 'valida'), aren't working when I need it:

```
var counter;
var tam;
var str;
var regex;

$(document).on('focus', '.valida', function(e) {
    regex = $(this).attr('pattern');

    counter = 0;
    tam = size_of(regex);
    str = generate_string(regex, tam);

    $(this).val(str);
});

$(document).on('keypress', '.valida', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var tecla = e.which;
    var tecla2;

    if(tecla >= 48 && tecla <= 57)
        tecla2 = tecla - 48;
    else
        tecla2 = String.fromCharCode(tecla);

    var t = type_of(regex, counter);

    if(counter < tam) {
        if(t != 'number' && t != 'string') {
            str = replaceAt(str, counter, t);
            counter++;
        }

        t = type_of(regex, counter);

        if(typeof tecla2 == t) {
            str = replaceAt(str, counter, tecla2);
            counter++;
        }
    }

    $(this).val(str);
});
```

I can't figure out the reason for that last script don't work, since I am using basicly the same structure used for the other two. Anyone can find a motive for this issue?

Comment: No, none of them are wrapped with `document ready` events, they are in separate js files (all of them), which are included in the dashboard.jsp file.

Comment: "workin when I need it" means that when I open a jsp page where exists a form with a field which has a attribute `pattern`, the script should take action and validate the input (character by character). No erroris displayed in the browser console (I try in Firefox and Chrome).

Comment: Ok, but that's not the only problem. In the code above, when the field get focus, the script should generate an `mask` to be displayed in the form, but this is not happening (ex.: if it's a date field, when it get focus should display `__/__/____`).

Comment: I am going to delete my useless comment to reduce clutter in a second. I would suggest trying to put enough of your app into a JSFiddle to demonstrate the problem as nothing is leaping out. (I usually solve my problems *myself* during that process). Cheers

Comment: that-s the problem: in jsfiddle the script works(link: http://jsfiddle.net/klebermo/f8U4c/79/), but in my application, don't.

Comment: Sounds too subtle to debug without the entire project :( As the JSFiddle works, start commenting out parts of the real project to match it until it starts working again. Might just be a side-effect of one of the previous addins (missing final semi-colon etc).